# Upgrading stretch to buster interface MAC issues

Tags: debian, networking, network-interface, mac-address, hyper-v

After upgrading `Debian` from `stretch` to `buster` I am encountering weird behaviour of the ethernet interface.

This installation runs on a Hyper-V host.

After rebooting, the mac address reported by the DHCP server is as such

```
5d291e0a0001000125f945b900155d291e0a
```

It is no known format of mac address to me. However,

```
ip address
```

reports correctly the old mac address.

What is going on and what can i do to get the behaviour to normal?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d316edf8-e492-4745-9ede-0688cbaf5edc/hyperv-and-file-servers-filling-dhcp-scope-with-invalid-leases?forum=winserverhyperv

Answer (score 0):

The explanation and the solution can be found  at [DHCP on Server 2012 R2 does not understand Fedora 25](https://mangolassi.it/topic/13497/dhcp-on-server-2012-r2-does-not-understand-fedora-25/15).